# Select all listview checkbox when we select the select all checkbox in android

Tags: android

I m using fragment where i m having the `ListView` and the select all check box.

Fragment class..

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

fb_custom_listview = (ListView) selectfriend_login
                .findViewById(R.id.friend_listview);

        select_all=(CheckBox) selectfriend_login.findViewById(R.id.select_all_checkbox);

        select_all.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

}
```

now having the `custom adapter class extends Baseadapter` 
where i m having one `ImageView` ,one `TextView` and one `checkbox` in the `layout` and inflating the layout in the getview method of the baseadapter class.everything is ok it display image,display text and display the checkbox also.so now when i click the `select_all(fragment class)` checkbox all the checkbox of custom adapter class should be checked and on unchecked all are unchecked.Here is the class
for custom adapter

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    private Context contxt;
    private ArrayList<String> user_friend_name;
    private ArrayList<String> user_friend_pic_url;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private int friend_counter=0;
    private ChangeUIListner mlistner;
    public static ArrayList<Integer> selected_friend_pos;
    public static ArrayList<String> selected_friend_uid;
    public static ArrayList<String> selected_friend_name;
    private List<Model> list;
    private ViewHolder viewholder=null;



    public CustomListAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<String> user_friend_picurl, List<Model> model) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.contxt=context;
        this.list=model;
        user_friend_pic_url=user_friend_picurl;

        selected_friend_uid=new ArrayList<String>();
        selected_friend_name=new ArrayList<String>();
        selected_friend_pos=new ArrayList<Integer>();
        user_friend_name=GetFriendDetails.user_fb_friend_name;
        inflater=(LayoutInflater) contxt.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


        System.gc();


    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return user_friend_pic_url.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView( int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub



        if(convertView==null)
        {
            viewholder=new ViewHolder();

            convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_listview_friendlist, null);

            viewholder.fb_friend_name=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.friend_nametextview);

            viewholder.fb_friend_pic=(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.friend_picview);

            viewholder.fb_checkbox=(CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.friendselectcheckBox);

            viewholder.fb_checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    int getposition=(Integer) buttonView.getTag();
                    Log.e("ITEM POSITION", "."+getposition);

                    list.get(getposition).setSelected(buttonView.isChecked());

                    if(isChecked==true)
                    {
                        if(selected_friend_pos.contains(getposition))
                        {
                            //nothing
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            friend_counter++;
                            mlistner.UpdateUi(friend_counter);
                            selected_friend_pos.add(getposition);
                            selected_friend_uid.add(GetFriendDetails.user_fb_friend_id.get(getposition));
                            selected_friend_name.add(GetFriendDetails.user_fb_friend_name.get(getposition));
                            Log.e("ARRAY SIZE", "."+selected_friend_uid.size());
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if(selected_friend_pos.contains(getposition)){
                            friend_counter--;
                            mlistner.UpdateUi(friend_counter);
                            int del_posi=selected_friend_pos.indexOf(getposition);
                            selected_friend_pos.remove(del_posi);
                            selected_friend_name.remove(del_posi);
                            selected_friend_uid.remove(del_posi);
                            Log.e("ARRAYLIST", "REM"+del_posi);
                            Log.e("ARRAY SIZE", "."+selected_friend_uid.size());

                        }

                    }

                }
            });

            convertView.setTag(viewholder);

        }
        else
        {
            viewholder=(ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            new AsyncDownloadImage(viewholder).execute(user_friend_pic_url.get(position));
        }


        viewholder.fb_checkbox.setTag(position);

        viewholder.fb_checkbox.setChecked(list.get(position).isSelected());

        viewholder.fb_friend_name.setText(user_friend_name.get(position));

        viewholder.fb_friend_name.setTag(user_friend_name.get(position));

        viewholder.fb_friend_pic.setTag(user_friend_pic_url.get(position));

        //new AsyncDownloadImage(viewholder).execute(user_friend_pic_url.get(position));


        return convertView;
    }


    class ViewHolder
    {
        int id;
        ImageView fb_friend_pic;
        TextView fb_friend_name;
        CheckBox fb_checkbox;
    }

    public class AsyncDownloadImage extends AsyncTask<String, Object, Bitmap>
    {


        private HttpURLConnection connection;
        private InputStream is;
        private Bitmap bitmap;
        private URL url;
        ViewHolder holder;


        public AsyncDownloadImage(ViewHolder viewholder1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            holder=viewholder1;
        }



        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            try {
                url=new URL(params[0]);

                try {
                    connection=(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    connection.setDoInput(true);
                    connection.connect();
                    is=connection.getInputStream();
                    bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
                    is.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                finally
                {
                    if(is!=null)
                    {
                        try {
                            is.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }if(connection!=null)
                    {
                        connection.disconnect();
                    }
                }

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            return bitmap;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(result!=null)
                {
                    holder.fb_friend_pic.setImageBitmap(result);
                }

        }
    }   

    public void registerUIupdateListener(ChangeUIListner lisnter)
    {
        mlistner=lisnter;
    }
}
```

as u can see i had used the single selection thing for the listview checkbox so its working fine and adding into arraylist for further operation.so how can we achieve the select all when the check box is click or select.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When u click selectAll check button then call selectAllFromList(value) function.
like

```
     selectAllButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {      
  @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
            //is chkIos checked?
    if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) 
    {
        selectAllFromList(true);
    }else 
    {
        selectAllFromList(false);
    }

  }
```

Following function will select all check boxes from the list:

```
  private void selectAllFromList(boolean b) {
            int cList = list.getCount();
            for(int i=0;i<cList;i++){   
                View sView = yourMainList.getChildAt(i);
            if(sView != null){
                CheckBox childCheckBox=(CheckBox)sView.findViewById(R.id.urCheckButton);
                    childCheckBox.setChecked(b);
                    childCheckBox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                      @Override
                      public void onClick(View v) {
                           if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) 
                            {
                                selectAllButton.setChecked(false);
                            }
                        }
                      });
                }   
            }   
        }
        });
```

Hope this one helps you

Comment: the selectAllFromList method is in the fragment class as mention above

Comment: Try this code in your class where you created listView not in adapter class. Sorry for inconvenience

Comment: +1 @DhananjayC great answer you save my lots of time and searching .. keep it up....